# np.where: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (38658637,) (9456,)"

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, data-processing

I have two dataframes with two different shapes:

1. `df_rts_1 #Shape: (38658637, 7)`
2. `df_crsh_rts #Shape: (9456, 6)`

I am trying to use **np.where** to update a column value **(df_rts_1['crash'])** to equal `1` based on certain condition as follows:

1. `df_rts_1['tmc_code']= df_crsh_rts['tmc']`
2. `df_rts_1['measurement_tstamp'] is between df_crsh_rts['Start_time'] and df_crsh_rts['Closed_time']`

**My Code:**

```
df_rts_1['crash'] = np.where((df_rts_1['tmc_code'].values == df_crsh_rts['tmc'].values) & ((df_rts_1['measurement_tstamp'].values > df_crsh_rts['Start_time'].values) & (df_rts_1['measurement_tstamp'].values > df_crsh_rts['Closed_time'].values)), 1, df_rts_1['crash'])
```

I am getting the error in the title. I am very new to Python/data science so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your both DataFrames contain:

1. *df_rts_1*:

   ```
       tmc_code  measurement_tstamp  crash
    0         1 2020-01-03 10:05:00      0
    1         1 2020-01-03 11:00:00      0
    2         1 2020-01-03 12:10:00      0
    3         2 2020-01-03 10:10:00      0
    4         3 2020-01-03 10:05:00      0
   ```
2. *df_crsh_rts*:

   ```
       tmc          Start_time         Closed_time
    0    1 2020-01-03 10:00:00 2020-01-03 11:00:00
    1    2 2020-01-03 14:00:00 2020-01-03 15:00:00
    2    4 2020-01-03 16:00:00 2020-01-03 18:00:00
   ```

To facilitate evaluation of the "between" condition, let's create the following
*IntervalIndex*:

```
interv = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_crsh_rts.Start_time,
    df_crsh_rts.Closed_time, closed='both')
```

And now, assuming that we have a current *row* from *df_rts_1*, let's construct
your condition:

- the "between" condition can be expressed as `interv.contains(row.measurement_tstamp)`,
- the equality of *tmc* / *tmc_code* values can be expressed as
  `df_crsh_rts.tmc.eq(row.tmc_code)`.

To check how they work, save the first row from *df_rts_1* as *row* variable:

```
row = df_rts_1.iloc[0]
```

and execute both contitions.

The first condition generates a *Numpy* array of *bool* type:

```
array([ True, False, False])
```

and the second - a *Series* (also of *bool* type):

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: tmc, dtype: bool
```

So to construct the final (single) *bool* value - whether this row
should have updated its *crash* column, the condition is:

```
(interv.contains(row.measurement_tstamp) & df_crsh_rts.tmc.eq(row.tmc_code)).any()
```

i.e. logical *AND* of both above conditions and *any()* - whether **any**
element of this conjunction is *True*.

And the last change, compared to your code:

- Instead of *where*, use *iloc[...]* where the first argument (row
  selector) is the above composite condition, computed for each row
  from *df_rts_1* (using a list comprehension) - which rows to update.
- The second argument is just *crash* - column name to update.
- Save *1* in the indicated cells.

The code to do it is:

```
df_rts_1.loc[[ (interv.contains(row.measurement_tstamp) &
    df_crsh_rts.tmc.eq(row.tmc_code)).any()
    for row in df_rts_1.itertuples()], 'crash'] = 1
```

For my sample data, the result is:

```
   tmc_code  measurement_tstamp  crash
0         1 2020-01-03 10:05:00      1
1         1 2020-01-03 11:00:00      1
2         1 2020-01-03 12:10:00      0
3         2 2020-01-03 10:10:00      0
4         3 2020-01-03 10:05:00      0
```

## Edit following questions in a comment

**Q1**. Are we using the indices from both conditions to access and update
the df_rts_1 dataframe?

Actually **not**. Note that:

```
[ (interv.contains(row.measurement_tstamp) &
    df_crsh_rts.tmc.eq(row.tmc_code)).any() for row in df_rts_1.itertuples() ]
```

yields a **list** of *bool*s, which even does not contain original indices.
It is then used in *.loc[...]*, so this is a case of **boolean
indexing**. Consecutive *True* / *False* elements of this list relate to
consecutive rows from *df_rts_1* and state whether particular row is
to be selected.

**Q2** and **Q3**. What does the *any()* do here? What *any()* helps us
achieve.

Look at the example for the initial row:

- the first condition (alone) states whether *measurement_tstamp* in the
  current *row* is between both dates in consecutive rows of *df_crsh_rts*,
- the second condition (alone) states whether the current *row* has matching
  *tmc* in consecutive rows of *df_crsh_rts*.

We require that **both** these conditions must be met for **the same row**
from *df_crsh_rts*, hence the *&* joinig them.

Note however that:

- *condition_1 & condition_2* yields a **Series** of *bool* type - whether
  consecutive rows meet both partial conditions:

  ```
  0    True
  1    False
  2    False
  Name: tmc, dtype: bool
  ```
- But we don't need any **Series** of *bool*s. We need a **single** *bool*,
  stating whether the above result contains at least one *True* value.

And just this transformation (from a *bool Series* to a **single** *bool*)
is performed by *any()*.

## Edit 2

As your data volume is huge, I came up with another, probably faster
solution. The idea is to:

- group *df_rts_1* by *tmc_code*,
- check only the *between* condition against intervals for the current
  *tmc*.
- to faster select proper intervals, use an auxiliary *Series* with
  intervals indexed by *tmc* (search by the index is faster).

To do it, define the following function, to be applied to each group:

```
def newCrash(grp):
    # Intervals for the current tmc_code
    wrk = intrv[intrv.index == grp.iloc[0,0]]
    if wrk.empty:
        return grp.crash  # Nothing found - no change
    wrkInd = pd.IntervalIndex(wrk)
    return grp.crash.mask([ wrkInd.contains(ts).any()
        for ts in grp.measurement_tstamp ], 1)
```

Then create the auxiliary *Series*:

```
intrv = pd.Series(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_crsh_rts.Start_time,
    df_crsh_rts.Closed_time, closed='both'), index=df_crsh_rts.tmc)
```

And finally run the update of *crash* column:

```
df_rts_1.crash = df_rts_1.groupby('tmc_code', sort=False).\
    apply(newCrash).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

For your (very small) sample data this solution works slower.

But after I inreased the size of *df_rts_1* to 40 rows, this solution
works a bit faster.

If you further increase the size of *df_rts_1*, the difference in speed
should be bigger (in favour of the second solution).

Check both solutions (original and this) on a sample of e.g. 100,000 rows
from  *df_rts_1* and write how long took the execution of both solutions.

Comment: Valdi, thanks a lot for the through explanation. This is a very elegant implementation and helped after hours of frustration yesterday. The code is still running since I have a  lot of rows but I will update you on it once completed.
I have some questions that can help me better understand this implementation:
1- Are we using the indices from both conditions to access and update the df_rts_1 dataframe?
2- I understand the logical "AND", but what does the "any" do here?
3- I understand the AND implementation but am still a little fuzzy on what .any() helps us achieve.

Thanks,
Hossam

Comment: Hi Valdi,
Thanks a lot, you are absolutely right! I ran both solutions (using timeit() )and got the following:
Solution 1: 72.26480119999997 seconds
Solution 2: 2.4047075999997105 seconds

The solution does update the crash values accurately to 1, and replaces 0 with 'nan' but I can change those to zero later.

I will now attempt this on a larger sample and let you know if I face any issues.

Valdi, thank you so very much and best of luck with all your endeavors!

Comment: Done, sorry am also new to Stack overflow :-D. Thank you very much again Valdi!